# Javamail and Javafx. Read and show mail embedded images

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, javafx

I use control named WebEngine (javafx) to show mail content downloaded by javamail. It's fine when the content is plain text or html with image src=http link, but when mail has embedded images (has content id in src) control dont show this images (of cource because has no idea where is it). What is the best control to show email? How to do it, when image storing in the memory. Maybe load mail in WebEngine is not a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

You need a [URLStreamHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) that handles the "cid" URL protocol and supplies the data from the appropriate part of the MIME message.  I believe you need to configure the URLStreamHandler by creating a [URLStreamHandlerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandlerFactory.html) and calling the [URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory%28java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory%29).  The trick, as I remember, is that there's no way to get the default URLStreamHandlerFactory so that your version can delegate to the default version for all the other URL protocols.

Alternatively, you can save all the attachments to disk and then process the html content before it's displayed to convert all cid: references into file: references.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that WebEngine isn't decoding and displaying multipart mime encoded messages such as what you are trying to process in your incoming mail.  If I recall correctly some browsers like IE didn't handle multipart mime encoded messages either (and maybe still don't).

What you can do is decode the multipart message yourself using something like [Mime4J](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/index.html) and then display the decoded content parts in controls (or external apps of necessary) based on the decoded mimetype you get from the multipart message.

- [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) will be able to display a bunch of mime types like text/html,
  text/plain, image/jpeg, etc.
- pdf can be displayed with [JPedalFX PDF Viewer](http://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedalfx-viewer/).
- text/plain could be rendered by [Label](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html).
- the various image/* mime types could be rendered by [ImageView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html).
- word docs and other formats not natively supported by any JavaFX controls could be written to a file and launched via [HostServices.showDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument%28java.lang.String%29) or [DeskTop.open](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29).