# javamail - read an email with cid:image

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I read Emails with JavaMail.
All is working.

My problem are Inline-Images, which are inserted by  cid:image
This images are not shown in the Email.

How is the workflow in JavaMail to show this images in an Email?

Can you give me some tips how to handle it?
I have found here this posting which helps me not really:
[Javamail and Javafx. Read and show mail embedded images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432432/javamail-and-javafx-read-and-show-mail-embedded-images?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the contents of the message?  You're going to have to do something so that URLs of the form "cid:" are able to be resolved to the attachments in the message.  If you're displaying the message contents in a web browser, you'll probably want to process the message text and convert the cid: references into a file: or http: reference and make sure the attachment data is available at that URL.